# Run React Native in an Android Input Method

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm building an [Android Input Method](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/creating-input-method) in React Native. I'm trying to do so like so:

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        // Create a custom react native root view
        ReactRootView reactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

        // Create the react instance manager
        ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                // .setCurrentActivity(currentActivity)
                .setBundleAssetName("entry.main.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("entry.main")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE)
                .build();
        reactRootView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "AndroidKeyboardTest", null);
        return reactRootView;
    }
```

The issue is the line `.setCurrentActivity(currentActivity)`, there is no Activity as far as I understand since this a `Service`. How can I get around this?